# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, sql

I am developing my first programm and am facing some problems please help me complete it
I have this code in c#:

```
SqlDataReader dr = null;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read()) 
{
client_id = dr["clientid"].ToString();
surname = dr["surname"].ToString();
othername = dr["othername"].ToString();
gender = dr["gender"].ToString();
date_ofbirth = dr["dateofbirth"];
nationality = dr["nationality"].ToString();
//age = dr["Age"];
residential_address = dr["residentialaddress"].ToString();
postal_address = dr["postaladdress"].ToString();
contact_number = dr["telephonenumber"].ToString();
marital_status = dr["maritalstatus"].ToString();
spouse_name = dr["spousename"].ToString();
email = dr["email"].ToString();
occupation = dr["occupation"].ToString();
typeof_id = dr["typeofid"].ToString();
id_number = dr["idnumber"].ToString();
id_expirydate = dr["idexpirydate"];
remarks = dr["remarks"].ToString();
picture = dr["picture"].ToString();
return true;
cmd.CommandText = null;
}
```

and the error message for this is     ............... date_ofbirth = dr["dateofbirth"];

Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists

(are you missing a cast?)

C:\Users\MICKY\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Godswill\Godswill\Personal.cs 249 28 Godswill

Answer (score 23):

You should cast *all* of those, rather than blindly using `ToString()`:

```
date_ofbirth = (DateTime) dr["dateofbirth"];
```

This will "unbox" the value as needed.

Of course, an easier approach here is to use an ORM or micro-ORM (such as "dapper") - then you just run:

```
var user = connection.Query<User>("select * from Users where Id=@id",
         new {id = 123}).First(); // (this is using "dapper")
```

where `User` is a class with properties that match the table definition, i.e.

```
public class User {
    public string Surname {get;set;}
    ...
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
}
```

Also; make sure you read about `using` here, i.e.

```
using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr.Read()) {...etc...}
}
```

this is even more important for connections etc, but it acts to ensure the resource is correctly `Dispose()`d even if there is an error. This replaces your "init as null, set to null at the end" code, and has the advantage of actually doing something ;p

Comment: Little gotcha that I spent 15 mins on: dapper will throw the same error if your class is not public, but instead private. A little bit obscure.

Answer (score 2):

When you use something like this

```
myVar = dr["myColumnName"];
```

the value of `dr["myColumnName"]` is seen by the compiler as a simple object. You should always cast it before assigning it that way:

```
myVar = (ExpectedType)dr["myColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_ofbirth = DateTime.Parse(dr["dateofbirth"].ToString());
```

or safe parse:

```
DateTime.TryParse(dr["dateofbirth"].ToString(), out date_ofbirth);
```

Comment: Why convert to a string and back if it's a `DateTime` underneath?

Comment: Parse or TryParse is expecting a string (not object)

Comment: Indeed, but when what you have is already a DateTime underneath, there is no point in serializing it into a string before parsing it back! A cast is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Convert.ToDateTime` on `dr["dateofbirth"]` and also on `dr["idexpirydate"]` (Since age would be `int` `Convert.ToInt32` for Age in case that is failing too !)

What is returned is of type `object` and you will have to cast it specifically to the DataType defined, not all of them are strings so `ToString()` won't be the choice for all of them.

Also it would be good to check for `DBNull` incase you are not using nullable datatypes